# Edit multitype keys in Windows registry from batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

Task - set default display resoltuion for all "Displays".

But - in registry is three of them:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{F92BFB9B-59E9-4B65-8AA3-D004C26BA193}\0000

HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{2D5BA881-99A8-4757-A06E-CB5493B97A39}\0000

HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{0F8D6C53-C039-4908-839F-1494115035F7}\0000
```

Need to edit entry in `0000`, but how it can be done from batch script?

If add `*` symbol - it's create new key.

Here is script content:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents>type reg.bat
REGEDIT4

; @ECHO OFF
; CLS
; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{*}\000]
"TestVal"="TestVal"
```

So - result is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{*}\000
```

What is correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This will enumerate all the keys under VIDEO and then add the Value and Data to each 0000 key.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('reg query "HKCC\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO"') do reg add "%%~A\0000" /v TestVal /t REG_SZ /d "TestVal" /f
```

See the help text for details about each command.

- [for /?](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [reg query /?](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)
- [reg add /?](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

Comment: It just close console (!?) without any results in Registry  :-|

Comment: @setevoy Is this being run from a bat file or directly on the command line?  Are there any error messages?  Try `@echo on` and adding a `pause` after this line to view the execution.  Try this command to verify the query results `for /f "delims=" %A in ('reg query "HKCC\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO"') do @echo %A`  These are a few suggestions for right off the bat.